# Why are my tag wiki edits rejected?

Tags: support

Today, I edited the [zombieland](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombieland) wiki and it was rejected. I don't understand why it was rejected, as it was a valid edit (IMO).

Is there any way to see why my edit was rejected?

Comment: Note that I (and others) have rejected quite a few of your wiki edits for exactly the reason Keen mentioned before.  Now that you know it is wrong to copy wikipedia, please go through any wikis you attempted to edit and make sure that none slipped through the review process (not everyone checks edits for copied content).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the links to the review histories for your tag wiki suggested edits.  They should work for anyone. (Let me know if I'm wrong)

> https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30329
>
> https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30328

Doing a quick google search of some of the text of your suggested edits, it looks like you plagiarized this blurb from Wikipedia.  There are two problems with this:

1. You're violating [Wikipedia's copyright](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License), which requires attribution, and
2. Wikipedia is not the Sci-fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange.  Their goals, audience, and content style are all different from us, and this means lifting their articles [isn't particularly useful](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1917/1027) to us.  Anyone can google a tag name and read up on the subject, [the tag wikis should provide some useful information and guidance for users of this site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1626/1027).